# Makefile Error on line 14: expecting target : dependencies

Tags: makefile, presto

I'm unable to run a Makefile of a project I downloaded (Presto's ODBC Driver).
When I run the make command I get the following error:

```
Daniel@Daniel-Laptop /cygdrive/c/TEMP/presto-odbc-master
$ make clean install
Error on line 14: expecting target : dependencies
```

I'm not quite sure what's wrong as the Makefile seems to be syntactically correct.
The Makefile can be found [here](https://github.com/prestodb/presto-odbc/blob/master/Makefile)

**UPDATE:**
I'm using Digital Mars Make Version 5.06

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Probably it would be better to ask on the project's mailing list. Maybe it's just a bug or a known issue. And they should be notices that this error may occur.

Comment: What version of Make are you using? (Try `make -v` if you're not sure.)

Comment: Digital Mars Make Version 5.06.

I've also asked this question on the mailing list, I will update with the answer here and there if I get any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 14 begins with a TAB character.  Your `make` command probably expects that line to be part of a make rule, thus the request for `target : dependencies`.

Supposedly, `presto-odbc` is supposed to be built with some other kind of make, i.e. Cygwin GNU make as per the `README.md`.

Comment: You're correct. I had to install GNU's make.
Thanks.

Comment: It's incredibly broken. doesn't compile not matter what I do.